# how to block 1.5 svn client from connecting to the server?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

how to block subversion 1.5 client from connecting to the server??. im able to block 1.4 client ( used python script, mergeinfo capability.). But to block 1.5, which capability should i use? and how to use? please help me

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to do?  Which operation are you using?  Can you post the code/info of how you blocked with 1.4, and which part doesn't work with 1.5?

Comment: there is start-commit lock example in the subversion hooks directory. I used that to block 1.4 client. Please go through that, You will understand the problem here!

Comment: why would you care?  I get that you want to block 1.4 to avoid not adding the svn:mergeinfo properties on commit, but why block 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly possible, as you are relying on new features in SVN to identify client's version. I have looked through [new features](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html) in SVN 1.6 and don't see any "new properties" - therefore your approach doesn't work here since has obvious fundamental limitations.